# Numerov Method on 1D Schrodinger

Tags: schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics, error-analysis

I've written a code that implements the [Numerov Algortihm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method) for a $1D$ time-independent harmonic oscillator.

I computed the difference between the calculated energy eigenvalues and the [analytical ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) for different values of discretization steps $h$.

The Numerov formula goes as $O(\Delta h^6)$, but the error from the grid discretization is $\simeq 1/h$, so the global error goes like $O(\Delta h^5)$.

In my code the result is $O(\Delta h^{3})$. This seems to be a pretty common issue, is this a truncation error? I can't find literature for this problem anywhere.

Just on theoretical grounds, is there a well-known problem regarding the Numerov algorithm to impute this  $O(\Delta h^{3})$ dependency to?

Comment: Hello! Here they say that the final error is "O(h4)" for the Schroedinger equation: http://physics.ucsc.edu/~peter/242/numerov.pdf (see the end of the document), don't know if it helps...